# Storing (and retrieving) functions by indexing them by address

Tags: c++, c++17, pointers

I want to implement a "service" of callbacks, where subscribers register or unregister a callback. I was thinking about indexing the callbacks by the function address, so that to unregister one would simply have to pass the same function.

So, disregarding threading issues, the simplest form of my implementation would be

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <cstdint>

std::map<std::uintptr_t, std::function<void()>> callbacks;

///https://stackoverflow.com/a/18039824/2436175
namespace {
std::uintptr_t get_address(std::function<void()> f) {
    typedef void(function_type)();
    function_type** function_pointer = f.template target<function_type*>();
    return static_cast<std::uintptr_t>(*function_pointer);
}
}// namespace

void subscribe(std::function<void()>&& callback) {
    callbacks.insert(std::make_pair(get_address(callback), std::move(callback)));
}

void unsubscribe(const std::function<void()>& callback) {
    callbacks.erase(get_address(callback));
}

void execute() {
    for (const auto& callback : callbacks) {
       callback.second.operator()();
    }
}
```

On the subscriber side, we would have things like:

```
void test() {
}
    
subscribe(test);
unsubscribe(test);
```

I tested and it would seem to work. See [code sample](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85cae182d43c14cd).

Assuming I will only use plain functions like `test` in this example (no lambdas, no bound methods...), is this a solid mechanism?

Comment: [Cross-posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72478477/1014587)

Comment: Does this work for all `std::function`s, or only those that reference a pointer to plain function?  It's worth stating any limitations.

Comment: @Mast Yes, now it's deleted there. I had initially received the suggestion to post the question here instead (that comment was removed though)

Comment: @TobySpeight Is the closing question "Assuming I will only use plain functions like test in this example (no lambdas, no bound methods...), is this a solid mechanism?" sufficient to specify the scope? Actually it would be interesting to know also how far I could stretch this (e.g.: what can I safely bind and retrieve by address?) but I didn't want to make the scope of the question too wide.

Comment: Assuming you use only pointers to plain function with the specified signature. `std::function` does quite a bit of adapting on assignment.

Comment: As an aside, function-pointers need not be round-trip-convertible using `std::uintptr_t`. Also, why not use the function-pointer directly, if they are all the same type?

Comment: @Deduplicator I do not think my code requires the round-trip convertiblity, just that the same function returns the same std::uintptr_t. I indeed did not consider what std::function might be doing under the hood at construction time, I liked the way it eases expressing "what kind of thing" we want to be stored in the map and passed as an argument; but it is also true that give the possibility to use it in the wrong way.

Comment: I answered a performance question here a short time ago, where the type-erasure from `std::function` turned out to be the culprit. It's just not only intent (can be called like such) but also a whole lot of mechanics which cost.

Comment: @Deduplicator So it would look like [this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bcda2a971cab201). (Significantly simplified)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Don't use `std::function<>` if you are only going to allow plain functions

I would avoid using `std::function<>` if your code doesn't handle something other than a plain function being bound to it. As Deduplicator mentioned, why not use regular function pointer types to store the callbacks?

## Prefer `using` over `typedef`

Especially for function pointers, the `typedef` syntax is a bit hard to read. Prefer [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), like so:

```
using function_type = void();
```

## Use `reinterpret_cast<>` instead of a C-style cast

Avoid C style casts in general, and use the best fitting C++-style cast instead. In this case:

```
return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(*function_pointer);
```

## Naming things

You named the result of the call to `target()` `function_pointer`, but it's not a function pointer; it is a pointer to a function pointer. I would rename it to `target_pointer` to avoid any confusion.

## Don't use an r-value reference in `subscribe()`

Your use of an r-value reference and subsequent use of `std::move()` is looking very dodgy. It might be fine if you only pass regular functions to it, but then there is no point of using move semantics, as `std::function` will not do any allocation then. Furthermore, doing something like:

```
foo(bar, std::move(bar));
```

Will resulted in undefined behaviour, as the [order of evaluation of the function parameters is undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). So the compiler is allowed to do the move first, then pass the moved-from `bar` as the first argument. You could call `get_address()` first and store the results in a temporary variable, but I would avoid the whole issue altogether and pass the `std::function` by value.

## Use `emplace()`

You can avoid having to call `std::make_pair` by using [`emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace):

```
callbacks.emplace(get_address(callback), callback);
```

## Consider using structured bindings

Since you tagged the question C++17, consider using [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to avoid having to use `first` and `second` if you iterate over a map:

```
for (const auto&[address, callback]: callbacks) {
    callback();
}
```

## Consider using a `std::unordered_set`

Since you don't care about the ordering of the callbacks, you can use a [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) instead. This will allow for faster insertion and removal into `callbacks`.

However, storing both the address and the function in a map is redundant; you can derive the address from the function as you are already doing. So instead you could use a [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). It is a bit more cumbersome to make a `std::unordered_set` of a `std::function`, but if you would only store regular function pointers, you can do:

```
std::unordered_set<void(*)()> callbacks;
```